# Microsoft Project & install options

Tags: c#, installation

I have 3 solution projects in C#.NET (Server, Client, Service). I am able to create setup for each solution individually.

But I need to build a single setup for all the three setups by providing options to select in those 3 (For ex: Radio Buttons). What ever option user selects that setup should be installed in their system.

Comment: I would have created a simple app to select among the options and run the appropriate installer based on the selection.

Comment: Thankyou. I found that we can include radio buttons in the setup wizard while creating setup. Can you guide me how to write backend code to select the setup from that radio button?